# Sign pdf using iText7 C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a private key in file for ex. "privatekey.pem" and don't know how to create `ICipherParameters pk = ;` could anybody help me? 
I'm trying to sign pdf using iText7.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using iText.Signatures;
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
/* ..... */

    protected void SignTest2()
    {
        bool isAppendMode = false;
        string dest = "signtest.pdf";
        string source = "test.pdf";
        int certificationLevel = 1;
        string reason = "Test reason";
        string location = "Warsaw";
        bool setReuseAppearance = false;
        string name = "Test name";


        ICipherParameters pk = ;

        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("fullchain.pem");
        X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[1] { bcCert };

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
        StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
        if (isAppendMode)
        {
            properties.UseAppendMode();
        }
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create), true);
        signer.SetCertificationLevel(certificationLevel);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance().SetReason(reason).SetLocation(location
            ).SetReuseAppearance(setReuseAppearance);

        signer.SetFieldName(name);
        // Creating the signature
        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-512");
        signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
```

Comment: I believe ITextSharp documentation / site has some valid examples have you looked at there site to see if there are any valid examples on how to do this at the bare minimum ?

Comment: I've been studying documentation for last 5 hours, unfortuletly i didn't find any working example (i tried a lot)

Comment: Having a `.pem` file doesn't guarantee that you have a private key. See https://serverfault.com/questions/9708 If you are sure it does contain a private key; use a tool to create a `.p12` file. A `.p12` file most certainly contains a public and a private key (and has some other advantages too). I've never seen anyone working with a `.pem` file to sign a document. That may explain why you find any documentation about it.

Comment: There is ptivate key inside I'am sure. Even this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15901273/9004965 doesn't work. It throws "invalidcastexception" while casting `(AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();`

Comment: Ok I solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I find a solution. It works if you have in "privkey.pem" file only the private key.

```
    private static AsymmetricKeyParameter readPrivateKey(string privateKeyFileName)
    {
        AsymmetricKeyParameter key;

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(privateKeyFileName))
        {
            PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader);
            key = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();

        }
        return key;
    }

    protected void SignTest2()
    {
        bool isAppendMode = false;
        string dest = "signtest.pdf";
        string source = "test.pdf";
        int certificationLevel = 1;
        string reason = "Test reason";
        string location = "Warsaw";
        bool setReuseAppearance = false;
        string name = "Test name";


        //ICipherParameters pk = Pkcs12FileHelper.ReadFirstKey("privkey.pem", null, null);
        ICipherParameters pk = readPrivateKey("privkey.pem");
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("fullchain.pem");
        X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[1] { bcCert };
        //ICipherParameters pk = signatureCert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
        StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
        if (isAppendMode)
        {
            properties.UseAppendMode();
        }
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create), true);
        signer.SetCertificationLevel(certificationLevel);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance().SetReason(reason).SetLocation(location
            ).SetReuseAppearance(setReuseAppearance);

        signer.SetFieldName(name);
        // Creating the signature
        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-512");
        signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
```

Comment: Note that a `.pem` key isn't that safe. If this key can be stolen, it's easy to abuse it. Also: with a software key, you will never get a green check mark in Adobe Reader. To get a green check mark, you need a hardware token with a key provided by one of the Certificate Authorities on the AATL (Adobe Approved Trust List).

Comment: calmly, I know how a qualified signature works. I just wanted to check if I can sign the document with the ssl certificate

Comment: *You* know that, but people reading your question and answer might not know them, so adding a caveat to your answer would be nice.